# Point system with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a game where I have a ball(the player) that is suppose to get from on side to the other of the screen. On both of the sides I have a SKSpriteNode that the ball needs to touch to score one point. When the ball touches the SKSpriteNode on on of the sides, then the ball needs to get to the other side and touch the other SKSpriteNode to score another point. And so on. How can I make so that when the game starts, the spritenode at the top is active, and when that is touched, the one at the bottom is active?

I've made a "incrementScore" function that adds one to the score everytime the ball touches the "points":

```
func incrementScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}
```

Then I have my two "goals" that the ball needs to touch to score:

```
func createGoals() {

    let goalTop = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Goal")
    goalTop.name = "Goal"
    goalTop.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    goalTop.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 465)
    goalTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: goalTop.size)
    goalTop.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    goalTop.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    goalTop.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(goalTop)

    let goalBottom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Goal")
    goalBottom.name = "Goal"
    goalBottom.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    goalBottom.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -435)
    goalBottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 
    goalBottom.size.width - 10, height: goalBottom.size.height - 10))
    goalBottom.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    goalBottom.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    goalBottom.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(goalBottom)

}
```

Also I've started on the didBegin contact function:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Player" {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
    "Point" {
        incrementScore()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the categoryBitMask to enable active bodies:

When you want goalTop to be active:

```
goalTop.categoryBitMask = category.Goal
goalBottom.categoryBitMask = 0
```

When you want goalBottom to be active:

```
goalTop.categoryBitMask = 0
goalBottom.categoryBitMask = category.Goal
```

Note: `category.Goal` is whatever number you use as your category

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I mean, I've added categoryBitMask to both of the goals, not sure why I didn't do that from the start to make it easier to understand what i needed help with. But when it comes to having one of the goals active when the other is inactive I don't really understand. I already added Goal in the "struct ColliderType { }" and it does add score when they "player" collides with either "goal".  So that part is working as it should.

Comment: You only assign the category when you want the object to be able to be hit, If the categoryBitMask is 0, then no collision will happen

Comment: Yes, but I still want the player to be able to collide with both goals at all times, but just not add point to both at the same time.

Comment: then why do you need to have it collide

Comment: Well since the goals are sort of the start and end of the "gamefield". I mean I could just add a maxY and minY for where the player can move but I thought it would be easier to just not make it possible to go through any of them but to collide with them.